# PostgreSQL string edit based on pattern

Tags: postgresql

Using PostgreSQL
I have a string that can have various patterns.
if the string has a "?" in it I would like to remove the first "?" and everything after it.
if the string has three instances of "/" I would like to remove the third instance and everything after it.
Any help would be greatly apprciated.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 0):

Use Postgresql's [string functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html):

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN POSITION('?' IN col) > 0 
      THEN SPLIT_PART(col, '?', 1)
    WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(col) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(col, '/', '')) >= 3 
      THEN CONCAT(SPLIT_PART(col, '/', 1), '/', SPLIT_PART(col, '/', 2), '/', SPLIT_PART(col, '/', 3))
    ELSE col  
  END result
FROM tablename
```

Replace `col` with the name of the column.
See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2669fadf85012caad4f04c7dc2216e18).